# Aws StepFunction path with waitForTaskToken

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am not able to forward the input path of the state "PublishIotCmd&WaitTask" to the next task "succedTask".

[state disgram picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jZHh.png)

Let's assume that the Input path of "PublishIotCmd&WaitTask" is {"fuzzy":"foo"}.

The "PublishIotCmd&WaitTask" is awaken from a external lamba, let's simulate it with:

```
aws stepfunctions send-task-success --task-token <the_token>--task-output {\"a\":\"b\"},
```

I am expecting that input path of "succedTask" is:

```
{
  "fuzzy":"foo"
  "taskresult": {"a":"b"}
}
```

This is the task definition:

```
"PublishIotCmd&WaitTask": {
 "Type": "Task",
"TimeoutSeconds": 600,
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "XXX",
        "Payload": {
          "token.$": "$$.Task.Token",
          "request.$": "$",
          "resultPath": "$.taskresult"
        }
      }
}
```

This state definition is generated from the following cdk code:

```
const publishIot = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'PublishIotCmd&WaitTask', {
  lambdaFunction: iotSendCommandFn,
  payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
    token: sfn.JsonPath.taskToken,
    request: sfn.JsonPath.entirePayload,
    resultPath: '$.lambda',       
  }),
  integrationPattern: sfn.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(TIMEOUT_WAIT_REPLY_SECONDS),
});
```

suggestion made by @Anton:
"Or pass the input as the output of PublishIotCmd.":  I guess that you mean something like that:

```
   "Payload": {
     "token.$": "$$.Task.Token",
      "request.$": "$",
      "resultPath": "$.lambda",
       "outputPath": "$"
    }
```

But this is still not working, I get only
{"a":"b"}

Comment: You want to pass input of PublishIotCmd to the input of succedTask? Then use an execution context (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html).  Or pass the input as the output of PublishIotCmd.

Comment: @Anton i have updated with your suggestion but still not luck.

Comment: @MarcoSinigaglia can you upvote the answer or accept the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to pass `resultPath` to `props` instead of `payload`.

```
const publishIot = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(
  this, 
  'PublishIotCmd&WaitTask',
  {
    lambdaFunction: iotSendCommandFn,
    payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
      token: sfn.JsonPath.taskToken,
      request: sfn.JsonPath.entirePayload,     
    }),
    integrationPattern: sfn.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
    timeout: Duration.minutes(TIMEOUT_WAIT_REPLY_SECONDS),
    resultPath: '$.lambda',
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marco, You don't need to specify output path for `PublishIotCmd&WaitTask`. Just specify payload for `succedTask` as below

```
"Payload": {
  "fuzzy":"foo",
  "taskresult.$": "$."
}
```

this way input of `succedTask` will be

```
{
  "fuzzy":"foo",
  "taskresult": {"a":"b"}
}
```